# moving scroll on chat window automatically

Tags: css, scroll

I'm designing a chat window and I'm using `overflow:auto` in CSS.
I want it continue with end of line, but scroll does not moving, and it's always move to top of the chat window.

Is there a way to do it automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using javascript it will be possible see the following

```
document.getElementById("id of your div").scrollTop = document.getElementById("id of your div").scrollHeight;
```